# Example of a second countable space but not locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

I am stuck trying to find an example of a second countable space but not locally compact.
Can you help me?

Comment: Any subspace of a second countable space is second countable. Take a second countable space you know well, and look for a subspace that is not locally compact.

Comment: Ah, of course, I can take a subspace from $\mathbb{R}$ which is not an intersection of an open and a close. Thank you!

Comment: Take a separable infinite-dimensional Banach space.